# Finding the next biggest integer in two arrays

Tags: python

I have two arrays, `arr_x` and `arr_y`. These arrays contain integers 1 to 20, no duplicates and not all integers from 1 to 20 are in these arrays. For example:

```
arr_x = [4,5,6,7]
arr_y = [16,15,14,13]
```

I'm counting up from 1 and lets say I get to 7, I want to find the next biggest integer that is in **either** of these arrays, and then perform an action if it is in `arr_y`, and do nothing if it is in `arr_x`.

Referencing the example it would find, the next biggest integer in either of these arrays is 13, and its in `arr_y`, so it would perform the action.

I've been stuck on this without nesting all these if's and for loops and it gets really sloppy, any ideas?

Comment: Is this one of the SPOJ problems?

Comment: Sort the arrays (n log n) and then do a binary search (log n)?

Comment: Nope, not related to SPOJ.

Comment: Do you want the fastest or the cleanest answer?

Comment: Fastest would be best, I used an array of 20 integers as an example but this will interact with arrays much larger

Comment: You have to specify the estimated or unknown size of the array then. Doing a python sort on 20 integers might be a waste of time. But if it's 1 million, it's probably best. Additionally the knowledge of the maximum number is important, as it might be better to do a Radix sort if it's small.

Comment: Sorting would only be best if you are going to do the operation on the same lists multiple times with different values.  Solution can be found in O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest answer I can think of: Filter out all values lower or equal to 7, then pick the lowest remaining value.

```
try:
    # Replace 7 with increasing variable if run in loop.
    if min(filter(lambda n: n > 7, arr_x + arr_y)) in arr_y:
        perform_some_action()
except IndexError:
    print('There is no next biggest integer.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I expanded on @Banana answer to include which list the value comes from so it should be simple to check if it comes from arr_y using...

```
if findNextLargest(arr_x,arr_y)[1] #to check if it is arr_y


def findNextLargest(arr_x,arr_y):
    res = False
    for i,each in enumerate([arr_x,arr_y]):
    #enumerate will mark which list it comes from
    #order is important so you can overwrite answer if found in X and Y, Answer Priority is given to Y

        filtered = filter(lambda n: n > 7,each) #filters using @Banana logic
        if filtered:res=  (min(filtered),i)     #grabs next largest using @Banana logic
return res #returns a tuple where first value is the next largest value and second is the list it comes from where 1 is y and 0 is x
```